# Firestore string isn't loading

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app with Firebase Firestore. My problem is, my title is getting "null" and I don't know why. I did exactly the same code from my **"description"** string (works perfectly) to the **"title"**, but it isn't loading inside the app.

The data is uploading normaly, but the **title** doesn't appears in the app.

I have the **"share post"** function inside the app, and when clicked it shares the image+title+desc+url and I realized that instead of *title* is the text **null**.
How could I solve this, please?

**Title turns to "null" when sharing post:**
[image: Share title "null"]

**Firestore structure:**
[image: Firebase Firestore Data Structure]

**My adapter:**

```
    public class BlogPost extends BlogPostID {

    public String user_id;
    public String image;
    public String title;
    public String desc;
    public String thumbnail;
    public Date timestamp;

    public BlogPost(){}

    public BlogPost(String user_id, String image, String title, String desc, String thumbnail, Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;

    }



    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getthumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setthumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

**My NewPostActivity.java:**

```
public class NewPostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ImageView newpost_image;
    private EditText newpost_description;
    private EditText newpost_title;
    private FloatingActionButton publish_btn;
    private ProgressBar newpost_progress;
    private Uri post_image_uri=null;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String curentUser_id;
    private  static final int MAX_LENGTH =100;
    private Bitmap compressedImageFile;
    AnimatedVectorDrawable uploading,uploadingComplete;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_post);


        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.newpost_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        newpost_description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newpost_description);
        newpost_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newpost_title);
        newpost_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newpost_image);
        publish_btn = findViewById(R.id.newpost_publish);
        newpost_progress = findViewById(R.id.newpost_progress);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        {
            if (checkPermission())
            {
                // Code for above or equal 23 API Oriented Device
                // Your Permission granted already .Do next code
            } else {
                requestPermission(); // Code for permission
            }
        }
        else
        {

            // Code for Below 23 API Oriented Device
            // Do next code
        }

        newpost_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setMaxCropResultSize(1920,1080)
                        .setMinCropResultSize(426  ,240)
                        .setAspectRatio(16,9)
                        .start(NewPostActivity.this);
            }
        });


        publish_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String title = newpost_title.getText().toString();
                String description = newpost_description.getText().toString();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(description)&& post_image_uri!=null)
                {
                    newpost_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    uploading =
                            (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_uploading);
                    if (uploading != null) {
                        publish_btn.setImageDrawable(uploading);
                        uploading.start();
                    }

                    String randomName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                    StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("post_image").child(randomName+".jpg");

                    filepath.putFile(post_image_uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    String postimage_url = uri.toString();
                                    String downThumb;
                                    curentUser_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    //compression
                                    File newImageFile = new File(post_image_uri.getPath());
                                    try {
                                        compressedImageFile = new Compressor(NewPostActivity.this)
                                                .setMaxWidth(200)
                                                .setMaxWidth(200)
                                                .setQuality(10)
                                                .compressToBitmap(newImageFile);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    compressedImageFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos);
                                    byte[] thumb_data = baos.toByteArray();
                                    StorageReference uploadTask = storageReference.child("post_image/thumbs").child(randomName+".jpg");

                                    uploadTask.putBytes(thumb_data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                                            uploadTask.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                    String download_thumb = uri.toString();

                                                    Map<String,Object> postMap = new HashMap<>();
                                                    postMap.put("thumbnail",download_thumb);
                                                    postMap.put("image",postimage_url);
                                                    postMap.put("title",title);
                                                    postMap.put("desc",description);
                                                    postMap.put("user_id",curentUser_id);
                                                    postMap.put("timestamp",FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                                                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").add(postMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                                                            Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this,"Post Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                            newpost_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                                            uploading.stop();

                                                            uploadingComplete =
                                                                    (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_upload_complete);
                                                            if (uploadingComplete != null) {
                                                                publish_btn.setImageDrawable(uploadingComplete);
                                                                uploadingComplete.start();
                                                            }

                                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void run() {
                                                                    Intent mainPage = new Intent(NewPostActivity.this,FeedActivity.class);
                                                                    startActivity(mainPage);
                                                                    finish();

                                                                }
                                                            }, 1000);


                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            newpost_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });


                }else {

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title))
                    {
                        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(publish_btn,
                                "Title can not be empty.",
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                        );
                        SnackbarHelper.configSnackbar(NewPostActivity.this, snack);
                        snack.show();

                    }else {
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(description)) {
                            Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(publish_btn,
                                    "Description can not be empty.",
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                            );
                            SnackbarHelper.configSnackbar(NewPostActivity.this, snack);
                            snack.show();
                        }else {
                            Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(publish_btn,
                                    "Please select image for the post.",
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                            );
                            SnackbarHelper.configSnackbar(NewPostActivity.this, snack);
                            snack.show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(NewPostActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(NewPostActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(NewPostActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
                } else {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                post_image_uri = result.getUri();
                newpost_image.setImageURI(post_image_uri);

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this,"Crop Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }




    public static String random() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int randomLength = generator.nextInt(MAX_LENGTH);
        char tempChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++){
            tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
            randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
        }
        return randomStringBuilder.toString();
    }


}
```

**My DetailActivity.java:** (where should retrieve data from Firestore)

```
public class DetailActivity extends DragDismissActivity {

    ImageView imgPost,imgUserPost,likeBtn,viewsBtn,shareBtn,deleteBtn;
    TextView txtPostTitle,txtPostDesc,txtPostDateName,blogLikeCount,blogViewCount;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String blogPostID;
    int count;


    @Override
    public View onCreateContent(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detail, parent, false);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(   v.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        blogLikeCount = v.findViewById(R.id.blogLikeCount);
        deleteBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
        shareBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
        likeBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
        viewsBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.viewsBtn);
        imgPost = v.findViewById(R.id.post_detail_img);
        imgUserPost = v.findViewById(R.id.post_detail_user_img);
        txtPostTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.post_detail_title);
        txtPostDesc = v.findViewById(R.id.post_detail_desc);
        txtPostDateName = v.findViewById(R.id.post_detail_date_name);

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
        String postTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        String postDescription = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
        blogPostID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("blogPostID");
        String postImage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postImage") ;
        String postThumb = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postThumb") ;
        //String userpostImage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postUserImage");
        //String postUserName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postUserName");
        String postUserID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postUserID");
        String currentUserID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("currentUserID");
        String postTimeStamp = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postTimeStamp");



        //Likes Feature
        likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Animatable animatable = (Animatable) likeBtn.getDrawable();
                animatable.start();
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostID + "/Likes").document(currentUserID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        if(!task.getResult().exists()){

                            Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                            likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostID + "/Likes").document(currentUserID).set(likesMap);

                        } else {

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostID + "/Likes").document(currentUserID).delete();

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });


        //Get Likes
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostID + "/Likes").document(currentUserID).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){

                    likeBtn.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_red_600));

                } else {


                    likeBtn.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.fontColor));

                }

            }
        });

        //Get Likes Count
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostID + "/Likes").addSnapshotListener( new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if(!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                    int count = documentSnapshots.size();

                    updateLikesCount(count);

                } else {

                    updateLikesCount(0);

                }

            }
        });

        if(postUserID.equals(currentUserID))
        {
            deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animatable animatable = (Animatable) shareBtn.getDrawable();
                animatable.start();

                shareItem(postImage,postTitle,postDescription);
            }
        });


        viewsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animatable animatable = (Animatable) viewsBtn.getDrawable();
                animatable.start();
            }
        });

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailActivity.this,R.style.MyCustomAlert2);
                builder.setTitle("Delete");
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",null);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Delete this post?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Post Deleted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                        deletePost(position);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });







        //SET POST IMAGE
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.placeholder(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));

        Glide.with(this).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(postImage).thumbnail(
                Glide.with(this).load(postThumb)
        ).into(imgPost);


        //SET POST DESCRIPTION
        txtPostDesc.setText(postDescription);

        //SET POST TITLE
        txtPostTitle.setText(postTitle);

        //SET IMAGE OF POST AUTHOR
        //User Data will be retrieved here...
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(postUserID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    String userName = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String userImage = task.getResult().getString("image");

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userImage).into(imgUserPost);
                    txtPostDateName.setText(userName);

                } else { }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public void updateLikesCount(int count){
        blogLikeCount = findViewById(R.id.blogLikeCount);
        blogLikeCount.setText(count + " Likes");
    }


    private void deletePost(int position) {
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").document(blogPostID).delete();
    }


    public void shareItem(String url, String desc, String title) {

        StringBuilder shareText = new StringBuilder();

        shareText.append(title);
        shareText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        shareText.append(desc);
        shareText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        shareText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        shareText.append("Check out Fire Blog App");
        shareText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        shareText.append("https://play.google.com/store/apps/");

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        i.setType("*/*");
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText.toString());
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(resource));
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                    }
                });
    }

    public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        try {
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            File file =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
            bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your json looks like?

Comment: Where is the line that you said it is null?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Isn't in the JSON. It's fine. The problem is that doesn't show nothing inside app. "Null" is when I share the post. In place of the title is showing "null". I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Can you remove unnecessary code ? and update the code what line is null

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine That's the point, I don't know what is causing this. There's nothing in logcat.

Comment: add me on discord Ticherhaz#7548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I just checked my other java classes, then realized that I didn't updated my RecyclerAdapter.java :p

Case solved. Thank you!

P.S. Make sure you have coded in all the necessary classes. Don't be like me...